# Running an API request for each UNIQUE value in column

Tags: python, pandas

So I have to run an api to get certain information on a city, the way I do that is not elegant but works, I suppose. The problem is that my column of 'Cities' contains a variety of different cities.

```
City      KWR1   KWR2   KWR3
Killeen
Houston
Killeen
New River
```

After running the api, my code fills in the first KWR1, KWR2 and KWR3. But the rest are left empty ofcourse, how do I make it read through the 'City' column and run the api for each location (I would want the City to be a value in the variable 'location' because of how I'm using the api.)

Here's the code im using to configure the api...(yes I'm slightly ashamed)

```
baseurl = "https://api.scaleserp.com/search?api_key=96E659E09E3B4382A03AB87D044E9F85&q="
url = (baseurl+type+'&google_domain=google.com&location='+location+'&gl=us&hl=en&no_cache=false&cache_max_age_minutes=10080&search_type=places&sort_by=relevance&time_period=last_week&num=20&output=csv&csv_fields=search.q,search.location,places_results.link,places_results.reviews')
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out, using a for loop makes it possible:

```
for location in df.City.unique():
```

use location as the variable in your api parameters